# Issue while merging two branches in Git

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have two branches master and Feature in Git. both branches are not in sync. I tried to merge these 2 branches but after merge I found many commits are missing. How to solve this issue. Below are the step which I performed

```
Checkout to master and did a pull 
perform git pull origin Feature from master branch
Resolve all conflicts and commit the changes
Push the code
```

Answer (score 0):

What you did is a wrong practice because you're pulling directly from feature to master assuming that after resolving conflicts you won't have any errors. So simply wrong. What you should've done is the following:

1. You should go to your feature branch. (`git checkout feature`)
2. Pull from master (`git pull origin master`)
3. Resolve conflicts if any
4. After resolving conflicts, test your code on feature branch.
5. After testing your code and running your unit tests (if any), you merge to master. (`git checkout master && git merge feature`)

So find your old master head commit using `git reflog`, and do this: `git reset --hard <commit>` and do what I told you to do above.

If you want to validate the files changed you're merging to master, before performing step 5 do this:

```
git checkout feature
git diff master --name-status
```

Comment: I will follow the steps which you suggest, Can you tell me how I lost the commits